# Laravel function calling with route or from another function

Tags: php, laravel, web, routes

I have two functions:
- 1st function has route: ‘test’, and I’m sending some values with GET parameters. (test?key=value), and that’s ok.

But, now I want to call 1st function from 2nd function, and send some other values...

How to create 1st function to receive GET parameters within function variables “function ($key){...”

Example:

```
function my_first($values){
    return $values['key'];

}
function my_second(){
    $something['key'] = 'Value';
    return 'Info from first: ' . $this->my_first($something['key']);
}
```

Then, I need to be able to call my_first() with 'test' route and send some parameters to $values variable.

I don’t know how to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: You can call `my_second` from `my_first` and sending `$values` to that function by `$this->my_second($values)`. And get $values in your `my_second` by `function my_second($getValues){ dd($getValues); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function my_first($key = null)
{
    return $key ?: request('key');
}

public function my_second()
{
    $key = 'Value';
    return 'Info from first: ' . $this->my_first($key);
}
```